# Active Directory, no mail attribute found

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, exchange-server

I'm hoping to regularly update a user table in a database with name and email addresses of all users on Active Directory using an app written in C#. I retrieve the users using DirectorySearcher.

```
 DirectorySearcher dirSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
 dirSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
 dirSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
 SearchResultCollection resultCol = dirSearch.FindAll();
```

This does return a list of users on the system but only returns the email address of one user.

I admit my experience is limited when it comes to Active Directory and IT Admin etc.  Am looking in the correct place to retrieve such information?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: This might be a silly question but does Active Directory link to Exchange? So if i have an email account running in Outlook, as well as my colleagues, should the mail attribute not be populated in AD?

Comment: Yes, if you're using Exchange, the `mail` attribute should be populated for all accounts that have mailboxes. The `mail` attribute corresponds to the "E-mail" field on the "General" tab in AD Users and Computers.

Answer (score 2):

*Attributes* of an *object* (the equivalent of *columns* of a *record*) in a directory service such as Active Directory may be **optional**. Meaning, they may be present or they may not be present.

This is a big difference from relational databases where all columns will always be returned for a record (although they may contain `null` values).

So in your case, only one user has an email address, and you may consider the absence of a value to be `null`.

Answer (score 2):

First to answer your question in your comment, yes Active Directory links to Exchange. In fact Exchange highly relies on Active Directory, 99% of Exchange user level settings are stored in Active Directory. Exchange uses AD as its user settings database, if you look at a user's attribute list in AD you can find tens of attributes names starting as "msexch".

Back to your major issue, **mail** is not the correct attribute for email address that used by Exchange server. The correct AD attribute you need to query is **proxyaddresses**. Please pay attention that it is a multi-value attribute because a user can have multiple email addresses. For example if it's my account:

```
smtp:dongmao@company.com
smtp:dong_mao@company.com
SMTP:maodong@company.com
smtp:mao_dong@company.com
```

The address with uppercase SMTP is the primary email address while others are all secondary. All of them can be used if you want to send an email to me.

So in conclusion, to achieve what you want

- Search attribute **proxyaddresses**
- Update your code a little to make it handle multi-value AD field
- You decide whether store primary email address only or store all addresses to your database. If primary only, filter out address starts with uppercase SMTP.

**Then what mail attribute is used for?**

- It's a contact attribute in AD to provide necessary contact information. Just like telephone number, mobile phone number, office, physical address and etc. It exists without any email system installed in your organization.
- In early version of Exchange (<2007), Exchange always kept the value of mail and primary SMTP address in sync. Started from Exchange 2007, Exchange only do a sync action when an Exchange admin runs Set-Mailbox. So it's possible that they are not in sync, or the value of users can be blank as in your case.

Comment: Thank's for your reply, very informative!  Unfortunately I'm also not getting the proxyaddresses attribute returning.

Comment: Do you have any other tool to retrieve AD data? We should isolate the issue to see whether they really don't have the attribute value or it's issue with your code. One option to check AD is PowerShell AD module:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rkramesh/2012/01/17/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-7/